# Facebook Library: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have an error at the page:

http://www.thalasoft.com/engine/modules/user/login.php

The Chromium browser says: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

And the Facebook Connect button does not work any longer..

Any clue ?

Answer (score 6):

You have both the deprecated Facebook javascript library loaded as well as the old one.  Remove the old one:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php"></script>
```

Keep the valid one:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId: '35944321698',
            status: true,
            cookie: true,
            xfbml: true
        });
    };
    (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol +
            '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    }());
</script>
```

Not entirely sure it will fix it, but I know mixing them is not supported.

Comment: Thank you so much! This one was killing me, the code that was loading FeatureLoader.js was outside my normal codebase which is why it was loading for me on our production site but not my local environment.

Comment: @StephaneEybert If you found the above answer correct please mark it so.